# Why does my link needs double click during test but works with single click manually?

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

Experiencing a weird failed test recently where the link element won't redirect on a single click or single clickWithJavascript.  When evaluating the element on intelliJ, the element.canInteract is returning true and then I let the click method run, but it's unsuccesful.  The link that's supposed to be clicked does get a box around it so I know it's being clicked properly.

Adding a .doubleclick to that same element redirects the page properly.

Adding method descriptions as they are somewhat custom:
canInteract returns: if element isDisplayed() and isEnabled()

clickWithJavascript runs a: `executeJavascript("arguments[0].click();", new Object[]{this.element});` after element is rendered and moved into view.

The issue I'm seeing is that if I manually click on the link during a breakpoint, I only need a single click for the page to go to the proper redirect.  Any reasons why this might be occurring or what to look into?

Comment: What are `clickWithJavascript`, `.doubleclick` and `element.canInteract`? These seem to be some custom code of yours that we are not aware of.

Comment: Is there a reason you are clicking with Javascript instead of using built-in `click()`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code sample, I'm not sure if your `clickWithJavascript` is working as expected.

Could you try changing it to this:

```
executeJavascript("arguments[0].click();", this.element)
```

It may be a better decision to use standard `element.click()` method here, instead of Javascript click.

Comment: The original method actually used just .click and was failing, so I played around and tried the .clickWithJavascript and .doubleclick just to see if I could figure out the issue.  Only the doubleclick worked.    Unable to change .clickWithJavascript as it's above my role level!

Comment: Instead of calling `clickWithJavascript`, can you try just running `executeJavascript("arguments[0].click();", element)` ? That will help you rule out whether or not it's an issue with the method.